# Mistake deal with mysql query: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource"

Tags: php, mysql

When I restart my page I received following mistake:

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

on this string:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['history_id'];"
```

What I did wrong in this code? Without following words in my MySQL query:

```
"WHERE user Like"
```

my code is work.

**My code**

```
  <?php
    $emp_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE user LIKE $login_session");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($emp_query)){ $id=$row['history_id'];
    ?>

<td>........</td>

    <?php }?>
```

Comment: The `mysql_*` methods are deprecated, and not safe, move on to mysqli or PDO

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with your `SELECT` query that's why it through error on `mysql_fetch_array` , try this way & use `%` if you want to match like `'$login_session%'` or `'%$login_session'` or `'%$login_session%'`

```
$emp_query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `history` WHERE user LIKE '".$login_session."'");
```

**NB:** move on to mysqli or PDO as *adeneo* advised